# MariaDB 5.5 Installation on top of MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I am trying to use MariaDB instead of MySQL on my windows 7 desktop.
Below are the steps I have done so far.

1. I have previously MySQL installed in my PC.
2. I have not uninstalled that MySQL.
3. Downloaded mariadb-5.5.30-win32.msi from mariadb.org
4. installed mariadb-5.5 but while installing it asked me to change the service name(by default it was showing service name as MySQL and port number as 3306) as I have MySQL installed with the same service name & port no. So I changed the service name as MariaDB & port as 3305.

Now when connecting from HediSQL by port no: 3305 and localhost I am able to connect to MariaDB and it is showing the 4 default databases as same as MySQL i.e. information_schema, mysql ,performance_schema, and test.

Same way I can connect from HediSQL by port no: 3306(i.e. the default port no of my previously installed MySQL), I am able to connect to my old MySQL and showed my other application databases.

Till now it is absolutely fine.

But how to connect the MariaDB from command line like I used to connect for MySQL using the below command: mysql -uroot -proot i.e. the MySQL client.

and also I can see that in MariaDB 5.5/bin all .exe files (except some extra .exe files) are as same as MySQL/bin. Is it using the same MySQL server internally. if yes then why I need to install MariaDB separately?

Now To use MariaDB shall I need to import my application DB from MySQL to MariaDB?

I am really confused between these two DB. Please help.

Regards, 
Sandip

Comment: why do you want mysql installed, not just mariadb?

Comment: I'm not sure if the same mysql client is 100% compatible between the two, but `mysql -uroot -proot -P 3305` _should_ work.

Comment: @ysth: Actually I am doing some research on MariaDB and I don't want to uninstall MySQL for that.

Comment: The below link might help others who are planing to move from MySQL to MariaDB: [MariaDB-vs.-MySQL](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/MariaDB-vs.-MySQL)

Comment: maria db is a fork from mysql, hence the similarities. However, there are internal changes which means that you cannot use the binaries of one for the other. Check out the maria db _website_ for a more detailed explanation of the differences.

Comment: to be able to use your data with maria db, you need to perform a backup from mysql and a restore in maria. I think a sql dump from mysql should be perfectly usable with maria.

Comment: @didierc: Yes you are absolutely right. It is as same as MySQL. The server is still mysqld, the command-line client is still mysql, the main configuration file is still my.cnf, and all connectors (e.g., the PHP, Java or Python connectors) happily connect as if nothing has changed. I have done migration on windows. the transition is really seamless.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish, you can copy data directory from MySQL's datadir to MariaDB's datadir .
Shutdown both MySQL and MariaDB  normally (e.g stop the service), and copy the files over.

Finally, remove ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 in the destination directory, because you'll mostly likely run into problem on startup (different log sizes are not handled gracefully)